# My Scrapy script very slow, extracts 100 items in 3 mins

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, data-mining

I am learning scrapy because I learnt it work asynchronously and thus faster than Selenium. But it actually takes about 3 mins to scrape just 100 items. I don't know why. Please I need help.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from  batt_data.items import BattDataItem
import urllib.parse
from selenium import webdriver

class BatterySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'battery'
#     allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = ['https://www.made-in-china.com/multi-search/24v%2Bbattery/F1/1.html']
    base_url = ['https://www.made-in-china.com/multi-search/24v%2Bbattery/F1/1.html']
    
    
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    # driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class,"list-switch-btn list-switch-btn-right selected")]').click()

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[contains(@class, "nextpage")]'),
             callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        price = response.css('.price::text').extract()
        
        description = response.xpath('//img[@class="J-firstLazyload"]/@alt').extract()
        chemistry = response.xpath('//li[@class="J-faketitle ellipsis"][1]/span/text()').extract()
        applications = response.xpath('//li[@class="J-faketitle ellipsis"][2]/span/text()').extract()
        discharge_rate = response.xpath('//li[@class="J-faketitle ellipsis"][4]/span/text()').extract()
        shape = response.xpath('//li[@class="J-faketitle ellipsis"][5]/span/text()').extract()
        
        data = zip(description,price,chemistry,applications,discharge_rate,shape)
        for item in data:
            scraped = {
                'description': item[0],
                'price' : item[1],
                'chemistry' : item[2],
                'applications' : item[3],
                'discharge_rate' : item[4],
                'shape' : item[5],
            }
                
        yield scraped
```

Comment: Have you tweaked your concurrency settings? How many pages per minute (not items) are you crawling?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was actually sending too many requests. I handled it by looping through a container that has all the items I needed. The updated spider did the job in less than 1 min